# Why object variable doesnt get updated inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have this piece of react code:

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {

let x ={ x1: []};

useEffect(() => {
  x.x1.push("hi")
})

console.log(x)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to know why the console always prints the value as an empty array for my key x1 in object x. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your component only render once (no state or props change)**

Even if your state rerender as if you force it, the `let x ={ x1: []};` will always be re-initialised for every new render.

If you want to see your `x` variable is updated, try to use `useRef` instead, and make your component re-render to see it inside `useEffect`:

```js
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState();
  const x = React.useRef({ x1: [] });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    x.current.x1.push("hi");
    setState(1);
  }, []);

  console.log(x.current);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Ok got it. But instead of using UseRef can UseState be used for the same purpose? But I guess it would cause a state overwrite than a state merge right?

Comment: Ya, You can also useState to achieve the same thing, for a state you will do a bit differently: setState([...state, "hi"])

Comment: useRef() is basically useState({current: initialValue })[0];

Comment: Yeah got it. Thanks Ryan!

Comment: Gladly to help ;)